# Why does git difftool not work with vimdiff?

Tags: vim, git

I just set up Git and set `git mergetool` to `vimdiff` and it works as expected.

If I set `git config --global diff.tool vimdiff`
it behaves strangely:

`git diff x y` will open less and display the changes in normal linear output form

If I use `git difftool x y` it just prints the output into the console - again in linear diff form.  (  The usual `@@ -1,40 +1 @@  -  +` form)

I tried all the different tricks with `external = vimdiff` and `tool = vimdiff` etc. Nothing works. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have `core.pager` set to anything?

Comment: ➜  ~  git config --list
merge.tool=vimdiff
merge.conflictstyle=diff3
diff.tool=vimdiff

Comment: Same problem here. Using a Mac so not sure if that's related

Answer (score 1):

I know its a bit old question. But I just had the same situation where I set `git config diff.tool vimdiff` and `git diff` doesn't open vimdiff.

But I am guessing there will others with same question coming to this page again in the future (like I did):

```
git difftool
```

It seems to do the job.